# Generate time slots based on duration and quantity in SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that for some reason stores rotas like this:

```
Rota      | Date_Start              | Position | Duration | Quantity | Rota_Slot_Type
----------+-------------------------+----------+----------+----------+---------------
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 1        | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2        | 15       | 1        | Support Slot
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 3        | 30       | 1        | Lunch Break
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 4        | 15       | 13       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 5        | 15       | 1        | Support Slot
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 6        | 30       | 1        | Lunch Break
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 7        | 15       | 12       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 8        | 15       | 1        | Support Slot
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 9        | 15       | 1        | Not available
```

Changing the table is not an option.

I have generated this:

```
ID_Rota   | Date_Start              | RowNumber | Position | Number | Duration | Quantity | Rota_Slot_Type
----------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+---------------
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 1         | 1        | 1      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2         | 1        | 2      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 3         | 1        | 3      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 4         | 1        | 4      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 5         | 1        | 5      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 6         | 1        | 6      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 7         | 1        | 7      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 8         | 1        | 8      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 9         | 1        | 9      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 10        | 1        | 10     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 11        | 1        | 11     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 12        | 1        | 12     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 13        | 1        | 13     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 14        | 1        | 14     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 15        | 1        | 15     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 16        | 2        | 1      | 15       | 1        | Support Slot
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 17        | 3        | 1      | 30       | 1        | Lunch Break
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 18        | 4        | 1      | 15       | 13       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 19        | 4        | 2      | 15       | 13       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 20        | 4        | 3      | 15       | 13       | Not available
```

(Top 20 rows, there are 46 in total)
This was generated using the following SQL:

```
select
    rs.ID_Rota,
    rs.Date_Start,
    row_number() over (partition by rs.Date_Start, rs.ID_Rota order by rs.Position, n.Number) as [RowNumber],
    rs.Position,
    n.Number,
    rs.Duration,
    rs.Quantity,
    rs.Rota_Slot_Type
from dbo.RotaSlots as [rs]
    cross apply
        (
            select top (rs.Quantity)
                n.Number + 1 as [Number]
            from dbo.Numbers as [n]
        ) as [n]
```

The part I'm struggling with is generating a Slot_Start column for each row. My anticipated output is:

```
ID_Rota   | Date_Start              | Slot_Start              | RowNumber | Position | Number | Duration | Quantity | Rota_Slot_Type
----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+----------+---------------
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 1         | 1        | 1      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 08:15:00.000 | 2         | 1        | 2      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 08:30:00.000 | 3         | 1        | 3      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 08:45:00.000 | 4         | 1        | 4      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 09:00:00.000 | 5         | 1        | 5      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 09:15:00.000 | 6         | 1        | 6      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 09:30:00.000 | 7         | 1        | 7      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 09:45:00.000 | 8         | 1        | 8      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 10:00:00.000 | 9         | 1        | 9      | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 10:15:00.000 | 10        | 1        | 10     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 10:30:00.000 | 11        | 1        | 11     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 10:45:00.000 | 12        | 1        | 12     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 11:00:00.000 | 13        | 1        | 13     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 11:15:00.000 | 14        | 1        | 14     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 11:30:00.000 | 15        | 1        | 15     | 15       | 15       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 11:45:00.000 | 16        | 2        | 1      | 15       | 1        | Support Slot
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 12:15:00.000 | 17        | 3        | 1      | 30       | 1        | Lunch Break
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 12:30:00.000 | 18        | 4        | 1      | 15       | 13       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 12:45:00.000 | 19        | 4        | 2      | 15       | 13       | Not available
372387412 | 2020-04-12 08:00:00.000 | 2020-04-12 13:00:00.000 | 20        | 4        | 3      | 15       | 13       | Not available
```

The first block is relatively straight forward - `(RowNumber - 1) * Duration` gives me the Slot_Start for all rows under Position 1. It falls down when you switch block to Position 2, Position 3, and so on.

Any help is gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get the Slot_Start time is to

- Order the rows (as you have there with RowNumber)
- Do a cumulative sum (running total) of the minutes duration of all preceding rows
- Add this cumulative sum to the Start_Datetime

In other words - instead of calculating `(rownumber - 1) * Duration`, you get the sum of Durations of all the relevant preceding rows.

You can use an expression like the following to calculate Slot_Start

```
DATEADD(minute, SUM(Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Rota, Date_Start ORDER BY RowNumber) - Duration, Date_Start) AS Slot_Start
```

Note you may need to put your code into a sub-query or CTE, so that RowNumber is calculated, or you could incorporate the ROW_NUMBER expression etc into your same set of calculations.

You could also use the ROWS explicitly within the window function, except then you need to account for the first row e.g.,

```
ISNULL(DATEADD(minute, SUM(Duration) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_Rota, Date_Start ORDER BY RowNumber ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), Date_Start), Date_Start) AS Slot_Start2
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=103667c4655972e602bb1c891d51f271) with data similar to what you have above (I started down a path before realising you were doing something different; however, the cumulative sum of Durations should still work).

Comment: I was so close! Thank you.

Comment: Yep, you definitely were - it's just one minor tweak to what you had.